# Call for Blog Posts for 4th of July

Tags: discussion, blog

The [Seasoned Advice Blog](http://cooking.blogoverflow.com/) is looking for someone to write a 4th of July (US Independence Day) post. You get to pick the topic, though of course we're looking for something related to both the holiday and cooking.

Writing for the blog is fairly easy. You can write your post however you'd like, whether that's directly into Wordpress or in a LibreOffice, Word, or even plain text document. Ask politely, and maybe even on a typewriter. Pictures are nice, but not required.

Ideally, we'd like to see a rough outline, draft, or similar by June 24, and a first draft by June 27th. We'll then get back to you with suggested edits ASAP, and the final post will go live on July 4.

We'd like to decide on a 4th of July post by June 1st. (Note that we're accepting posts for other dates as well)

If you'd like to write a blog post, and you're committed to writing it, please pitch it in an answer to this question. Please include when you need our acceptance by (to allow yourself enough time to plan, cook, write, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, we didn't get anybody proposing to write such a post. But we admins decided to nevertheless prepare a holiday special for you, and some community members are helping along. It will go online a few days before the holiday. Watch the community bulletin!